# Tricky HTML layout

Tags: html, css

Can anyone think of a way to approach converting the following scheme into a non-table html layout?

[image]

A few things worth mentioning, perhaps.

- Only the central block is
  mandatory (and should turn into a normal
  square block if it is the only one
  there).
- The total number of blocks is unpredictable, so layout should be easily expandable (and hence non-table).
- Exact left alignment of the text in
  all blocks is not crucial.
- No gaps other than shown are allowed
- Gray background can be semi-transparent,
  so no overlap is allowed too.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Probably better asked on http://doctype.com/

Comment: @etranger does the text wrap around the the vertical columns too? I imagine something similar to this could be achieved in JS

Comment: vertical columns should contain no text, if that answers. entire image is a block element.

Comment: Do you plan to insert text into `<p>` tags or something similar?

Comment: well, not sure how that affects the problem, but specific container element for text is irrelevant. let's say each of the 'text' items is to be placed in a div.

Comment: godamn it's hard I gave it a go, would take too long to do this though

Comment: Call me a heretic but this is ridiculously easy with tables. Don't blindly follow best practices when they hamstring your productivity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved, though not perfect with dynamic margins (calculated for each element in js/php/whatever) and the narrow elements needing a dynamically calculated height.

[image]

And the screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 12):

Ok.. it's VERY hard :) ..btw, if the text inside of it is 'static', you could do some tricks with floats and negative margins this way:

http://www.jsfiddle.net/steweb/Xa5X6/

I know it's not the best result, but it could be a way to start with :)

markup:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="column">
        <div id="sq-1"></div>
        <div id="rect-1"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <div id="sq-2"></div>
        <div id="rect-2"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="column main">
        <div class="text-container-1">
            <div class="text-1">
                text 
            </div>
            <div class="text-2">
                text 
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="text-3">text </div>
        <div class="text-4">text</div>
        <div class="text-5">text</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.wrapper{
    overflow:hidden;
    background:#777;
    display:inline-block;
}
.column{
    float:left;
}
#sq-1{
    width:20px;
    height:21px;
}
#sq-2{
    width:20px;
    height:21px;
    margin-top:20px;
    border-top:2px solid #FFFFFF;
}
#rect-1{
    height:104px;
    border-right:2px solid #FFFFFF;
}
#rect-2{
    height:82px;
    border-right:2px solid #FFFFFF;
}

.text-container-1{
    width:200px;
    border-right:2px solid #FFFFFF;
}
.text-1, .text-2{
    border-bottom:2px solid #FFFFFF;
}
.text-3{
    float:left;
    width:220px;
    margin-top:-44px;
    padding-top:54px;
    padding-bottom:10px;
    border-bottom:2px solid #FFFFFF;
    border-right:2px solid #FFFFFF;
}
.text-4{
    float:left;
    width:240px;
    margin-left:-222px;
    margin-top:-44px;
    padding-top:84px;
    border-bottom:2px solid #FFFFFF;
    border-right:2px solid #FFFFFF;
}
.text-5{
    float:left;
    width:260px;
    margin-left:-242px;
    margin-top:-44px;
    padding-top:104px;
    border-bottom:2px solid #FFFFFF;
    border-right:2px solid #FFFFFF;
}
```

In this example, you have to assign static heights to the elements on the left. Moreover, the negative margins of the elements on the right are static too.

static text => static dimensions/margins => a kind of weird result

If the text is dynamic, I think achieving a result without using JS and/or tables is almost impossible, also because these 'L' elements and theirs widths/heights are hard to manage.

dynamic text  => swearing

Comment: As much as I appreciate your effort (+1!), it's a bit off here and there (I'm using firefox on a mac). I have solved the issue, but thank you very much for all your help :)

Answer (score 0):

use absolute positioning and layer the divs by the zindex of the div

Comment: I was thinking there might be some zindexing here too.

Answer (score 0):

Define a CSS template for adding each component. One for the vertical part and the other for the horizontal part as L shapes are not possible directly and add them as per your requirement dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have a wrapper and inside that, you should declare a separate div for each text layer. float that left and some margins will fix that. Try to declare every div nested so that the divs can expand accordingly.